# Retrieve x/y values from a hist() graph

Tags: r, data-structures, histogram

Let's say I graph using the following command:

```
hist(rnorm(100, mean = 100, sd = 40), breaks=7)
```

How can I retrieve the x/y values for the graph? I mean I realize hist works in ranges, but even then, how can I get the ranges and the plotted y values of the barplot?

I have tried something as simple as:

```
> hist(rnorm(100, mean = 100, sd = 40), breaks=7)$x
[1] "rnorm(100, mean = 100, sd = 40)"
```

But as you can see no luck.

I have seen this post ([retrieve Y value from density function of given X value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957905/retrieve-y-value-from-density-function-of-given-x-value)), but it relates to a density function and the answer seems to approximate the function.

Comment: As a general piece of advice, when looking into the details, assign your function to something, e.g. `tmp <-  hist(rnorm(100, mean = 100, sd = 40), breaks=7)` and then do `str(tmp)` to see what's in it.  Also, `?hist` tells you about the return value as well.  Adding `$x` was a good guess, but note that it did a partial name match to `$xname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this

```
set.seed(99)
foo <- hist(rnorm(100, mean = 100, sd = 40), breaks=7, plot =  FALSE)
foo
# $breaks
# [1] -50   0  50 100 150 200
# 
# $counts
# [1]  2 11 34 47  6
# 
# $density
# [1] 0.0004 0.0022 0.0068 0.0094 0.0012
# 
# $mids
# [1] -25  25  75 125 175
# 
# $xname
# [1] "rnorm(100, mean = 100, sd = 40)"
# 
# $equidist
# [1] TRUE
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "histogram"
```

and only "x" and "y"

```
foo$breaks
# [1] -50   0  50 100 150 200
foo$counts
# [1]  2 11 34 47  6
```

or alternatively `mids` in place or `breaks` cf. [Marat Talipov's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830058/retrieve-x-y-values-from-a-hist-graph/34830114#comment57401911_34830114)'s comment below.

```
foo$mids
# [1] -25  25  75 125 175
```

Comment: `breaks` and `counts` are of different length. I'd suggest to use `mids` instead of `breaks`

Comment: Thank you both, this is what I was looking for.